# Single Pole Light Switch 3 Black Wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

not sure if I can get help with this but wanted to present my issue.

I've been installing smart light switches throughout the house and have had no issues.
Ran into a unique light switch this evening where one of the three black wires is wrapped around the side screw.

Now after some research I know it's connected to the bathroom fan as well as the bathroom light.

Does anyone know the proper way to wire this into my new light switch which has

LIVE
LOAD IN
GROUND
NEUTRAL

I know where ground and neutral go, copper and white wires.
I know two of the black wires go into live and load, but I'm not sure what I do with the wire wrapped around the side screw shown in the attached image.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The wire wrapped around the screw and the wire "stabbed" into the port next to it are connected together internally within the switch.  With the switch off, test for voltage to determine if the lone wire, on the bottom of the switch, is the hot (line) or if the two connected wires, on the top, are together the hot (line).  The two wires currently connected together on your existing switch should be again connected together on your new switch.

Good Luck,
Volt-Ron

Comment: I only have 4 slots so do I create a wire twist with two of them?
I have ground, neutral, load and load in.

Answer (score 1):

### Time to pigtail

You'll need to use a short length of appropriate wire (12AWG black solid THHN always works) nutted to the black wire that was in the top stab and the black wire from the corresponding screw to connect the switch to your wiring.  This is called "pigtailing" in the electrical world.

Once you do that, you connect the always-hot of the two free wires to Line on the smart switch, the remaining free wire to the Load terminal on the smart switch, and then proceed to pigtail the Neutral and Ground terminals on the smart switch to their respective bundles in the back of the box (white and bare).

Comment: Great! So I don't need to find out which one is the live wire.. simply purchase a 12AWG black solid THHN, take the top backstabbed wire, and the side wrapped around wire and create a pigtail.